# neat voltage divide sequence

Tags: voltage-divider

I am learning voltage dividing and created an array of different values to get a broader perspective and found this repeating sequence. Can anyone explain why the combo of r1 as 6000 ohm and r2 of 1500 ohm will always result with

voltage in x 2 / 10?

python to support

```
r1 = 6000
r2 = 1500

digits = [96, 48, 24, 12, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1]

def voltdivide(voltagein):
    dividby = r1 + r2
    LaResistawnce = r2 / dividby
    sum = voltagein * LaResistawnce
    return(round(sum, 2))

for n in digits:
    print(voltdivide(n))

print('\n\r ▲ voltage divide '
      '\n\r ▼ double divided by 10'
      '\n\r')

for n in digits:
    nn = n * 2
    movedeci = nn / 10
    print(round(movedeci, 2))


19.2
9.6
4.8
2.4
1.8
1.0
0.6
0.4
0.2

 ▲ voltage divide 
 ▼ double divided by 10

19.2
9.6
4.8
2.4
1.8
1.0
0.6
0.4
0.2
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Why would it be anything else? Vout = Vin * (R2 / (R1 + R2))... R1 and R2 form a ratio, in your case, 1/5. You would get the same result with R1 = 12k and R2 = 3k because it is the same ratio.

Comment: @RonBeyer. You should post your comment as an answer. It is simple but the truth, which the OP is somehow missing.

Answer (score 3):

Voltage divider equation: $$V_{out} = V_{in}*\frac{R2}{R1+R2}$$

$$V_{out} = V_{in}*\frac{1500}{6000+1500}$$

$$V_{out} = V_{in}*\frac{2}{10}$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f77M6n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>